# Let Posts be stored in another table

Tags: posts, wp-list-table

I am trying to develop a plugin that creates a new table in the Wordpress database and I want to store there some kind of posts I create.

I am trying to understand how to "clone" the Wordpress Posts/Add New/Categories/Tags and store the posts not in wp_posts, but in another table (eg.: wp_special_posts).

At the moment I have the function that creates the table at the plugin activation, I created the page that grabs the information from the DB and display them using *WP_List_Table*, but I do not have an idea on how, and if it is possible, to clone those sections.

And help? Hint?

**UPDATE**

I want to create a product section with its own table, called *wp_product_instore*, and I also want to use the standard *post-new.php* interface, but put the posts in the *wp_product_instore* table instead of *wp_posts*.

Comment: what are those special posts? Why store them seperately? Are they of separate post type?

Comment: Special posts could be posts, but I do not want to store them in the wp_posts table.
I prefer to have them in a different table.
I want a product catalog...updating the question!

Comment: Why would you want such a thing? Could you not just use custom post types? E.g. a Product post type? I see little to no advantages in doing this

Comment: Because if I want to export the data I can export just that table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `save_post` action hook as shown below but write custom insert/update queries to save information in a different table.

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_product_data');
function save_product_data($post_id) {
//verify nonce and all other code...
$title = $_POST['post_title'];    //example variable
$wpdb->query(
$wpdb->prepare(
" INSERT into wp_product_instore ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value ) values ( $post_id, 'post_title', $title )" ));
//likewise you save all other variables for the post.
}
```

PS: This code hasn't been test run. Please modify to your need.

Comment: Thank you, I made something like that: `public function save_post($post_id) {......global $wpdb;
      
      $wpdb->insert( 
          $wpdb->prefix.'product_instore', 
          array( 
              'prod_name' => 'title',
              'prod_description'=>'Lorem Ipsum....'));......}

But your hint is to write custom insert/update interface too?

Comment: @Mark I think both are similar and may be your code looks more standard!